# C++: portability of Unicode string literals

Tags: c++, unicode, string-literals

While debugging on gcc, I found that the Unicode literal `u"万不得已"` was represented as `u"\007\116\015\116\227\137\362\135"`. Which makes sense -- `万` is 0x4E07, and 0x4E in octal is 116.

Now on Apple LLVM 9.1.0 on an Intel-powered Macbook, I find that that same literal is not handled as the same string, ie:

```
u16string{u"万不得已"} == u16string{u"\007\116\015\116\227\137\362\135"}
```

goes from `true` to `false`. I'm still on a little-endian system, so I don't understand what's happening.

NB. I'm not trying to use the correspondence `u"万不得已"` == `u"\007\116\015\116\227\137\362\135"`. I just want to understand what's happening.

Comment: Unicode is Unicode, Encoding is Encoding.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : what does that mean? Why does the encoding differ between compilers?

Comment: xaxxon: updated.

Comment: live code: https://godbolt.org/g/e3QkUf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I found that the Unicode literal `u"万不得已"` was represented as `u"\007\116\015\116\227\137\362\135"`

No, actually it is not.  And here's why...

`u"..."` string literals are encoded as a `char16_t`-based UTF-16 encoded string on all platforms (that is what the `u` prefix is specifically meant for).

`u"万不得已"` is represented by this UTF-16 codeunit sequence:

```
4E07 4E0D 5F97 5DF2
```

On a little-endian system, that UTF-16 sequence is represented by this raw byte sequence:

```
07 4E 0D 4E 97 5F F2 5D
```

In octal, that would be represented by `"\007\116\015\116\227\137\362\135"` ONLY WHEN using a **`char`-based** string (note the lack of a string prefix, or `u8` would also work for this example).

`u"\007\116\015\116\227\137\362\135"` is NOT a `char`-based string!  It is a **`char16_t`-based** string, where each octal number represents a separate UTF-16 codeunit.  Thus, this string actually represents this UTF-16 codeunit sequence:

```
0007 004E 000D 004E 0097 005F 00F2 005D
```

That is why your two `u16string` objects are not comparing as the same string value.  Because they are really not equal.

You can see this in action here: [Live Demo](https://ideone.com/ZEabz7)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. It means the debugger is wrong. What I don't now understand is why the equivalence held on gcc. (gcc 7.3.0 on Cygwin.)

Comment: And NB I just reran the test to confirm gcc behaviour.

Comment: @Mohan that means the debugger is displaying the **raw bytes** of the `u16string` (which makes sense, if the debugger does not support displaying `char16_t` data as normal characters), and doing so in octal (odd, why not hex?), but I would not expect it to include the `u` prefix on such a raw string. But there is no way that `u16string{u"万不得已"} == u16string{u"\007\116\015\116\227\137\362\135"}` should ever be true on any compiler.  If it is, that is a bug that should be reported to the compiler vendor.

Comment: It does include the u prefix. Now you've pointed it out it's clear that's a bug.

Comment: @Mohan The debugger is likely displaying the `u` prefix because the data is `char16_t`, but then it is displaying the raw 8bit bytes instead of the native 16bit values because `char16_t` can go up to 0xFFFF (decimal 65535) so most values are simply too large to handle in octal, which has a max value of 0x1FF (decimal 511).